# socket handle leak in pyzmq?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq, resource-leak, handle-leak

Hi good people of StackOverflow.

I'm using pyzmq and I've got some long-running processes, which led to a discovery that socket handles are being left open.  I've narrowed the offending code down to the following:

```
import zmq

uri = 'tcp://127.0.0.1'
sock_type = zmq.REQ
linger = 250

# Observe output of lsof -p <pid> here and see no socket handles

ctx = zmq.Context.instance()
sock = ctx.socket(sock_type)
sock.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, linger)
port = sock.bind_to_random_port(uri)

# Observe output of lsof -p <pid> here and see many socket handles

sock.close()  # lsof -p <pid> still showing many socket handles
ctx.destroy()  # Makes no difference
```

pyzmq version is pyzmq-13.1.0

Either there is a bug in pyzmq, or I'm doing something incorrectly.  I hope you can help me!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a chat with pieterh and minrk on #zeromq, we found the cause.

`ctx.destroy()` in 13.1.0 has an indentation bug so it only calls `Context.term()` if there is an unclosed socket.

Workaround: call `ctx.term()` instead, and make sure all of your sockets are closed before you do.